# Using ODBC::dbConnect and dplyr to connect to Sybase IQ database - table name not found

Tags: r, dplyr, odbc, dbplyr

I can connect to my Sybase IQ 16 database using a connection string such as:

```
myDB_conn <- dbConnect(odbc(), "MyDSN_Name")
```

When I run this command the connections view shows a list of databases and corresponding tables/views. However when I try to use the logic laid out [here](https://db.rstudio.com/getting-started/database-queries) specifically naming the view I keep receiving an error about my view not being found.

```
test <- tbl(myDB_conn, "OFFSHORE_BOB.SOME_VIEW_OR_TABLE_NAME")
```

In the connection window I can see the database and view but when I use the code above I receive a table name not found.

```
nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1374: 42S02: [Sybase][ODBC Driver][Sybase IQ]Table 'OFFSHORE_BOB.SOME_VIEW_OR_TABLE_NAME' not found
```

I have also looked at listing the tables in the OFFSHORE_BOB schema and I can see the table of interest in there:

```
y <- dbListTables(gopher_conn, schema = 'OFFSHORE_BOB')
```

I then searched for the view of interest and I can see it there so I am stumped as to why I can not use this code

```
test <- tbl(myDB_conn, "OFFSHORE_BOB.SOME_VIEW_OR_TABLE_NAME")
```

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `OFFSHORE_BOB`? The database or schema? If database, connections usually connect directly to databases, so this period qualifying name is not necessary. If schema, look into `in_schema()`.

Comment: Try `tbl(myDB_conn, "SOME_VIEW_OR_TABLE_NAME", schema("OFFSHORE_BOB"))`

Comment: @r2evans I tried your suggestion but I am getting the same error. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely want the `in_schema` command from dbplyr. For example:

```r
schema = "OFFSHORE_BOB"
tbl_name = "SOME_VIEW_OR_TABLE_NAME"

remote_table <- tbl(db_connection, from = in_schema(schema, tbl_name))
```

Then `show_query(remote_table)` should return something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "OFFSHORE_BOB"."SOME_VIEW_OR_TABLE_NAME"
```

(The quotation marks are inserted by dbplyr in case your table or schema name contains non-standard characters. E.g. `abc-123` and `3-4` are not acceptable table names by themselves, but quoted `"abc-123"` and `"3-4"` they can be table or schema names.)

Note that you can also include a database name in with the schema name should you need to:

```r
remote_table <- tbl(db_connection, from = in_schema(paste0(db,".",schema), table_name))
```